# Sync a layer in QGIS to a layer that is on a website that is updated regularly

Tags: qgis, parcel, web, online

So I have downloaded the property parcel layer from the website https://maps1.larimer.org/gvh/?Viewer=LIL and I have added attribute information to the parcel layer in QGIS. However, the parcel layer on the website changes regularly and I was curious if there is a way for my layer in QGIS to update automatically when the layer on the website changes without altering the existing attribute information that I have already entered?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a download link at that URL so I can't describe exactly how this would work, but one way would be to put your additional data into a table (a non-spatial table) and use QGIS' "join" functionality to link the table to the spatial data you've got from the site.

For this you need a column in the spatial data that identifies each element and links it to a similar column in the non-spatial, joined table. If the spatial data is changed then as long as the identifiers don't change then the links to the joined table will be maintained. Often you'll use some sort of official ID code for the linking identifier column.

There's probably better/fuller tutorials online, here's a quick guide.

I have a map of counties with a "code" column. I create a new vector layer with no geometry and a code column alongside a "population" column which will be numbers to associate with each county:

[image]

I then go to the county layer and access its "join" dialog (right-click, properties, "join") and define the join to the new table with no geometry:

[image]

that done and "Apply" clicked, I can now toggle editing on the new table and open the attribute table of the counties. Even though the county layer isn't in edit mode, I can still edit the columns of the joined table and add the population info:

[image]

I can't even change the county map data here because the layer isn't in edit mode! But if I were to get a new county map data file, it would still match to the same features by code. If all the codes change then you're stuck, but if you've not got anything to link the data I'm not sure what you'll do anyway.

After saving the edits to the joined table, you can open it and see the records I created:

[image]

there are no entries for counties I've not filled in yet, but they appear as missing in the augmented county attribute table.

There's a bit more you can do with joins and its very powerful so check it out in the qgis docs and online tutorials.

Comment: So if I wanted to automate this process I am guessing its best to put all of these steps in a python script. The reason why I ask is that my coworkers have no GIS knowledge so I have been told to automate as many things as possible.

Comment: If you want to automate all this then yes, Qgis-Python might be a solution, depends how much you need to automate, and how often, and why. Does the spatial data change? Do coworkers need to map these things etc? This is turning into a process consultation.

Comment: The boundaries of the parcels sometimes change and sometimes the parcels are subdivided into multiple smaller parcels.

Comment: This is getting out of scope for here. If parcels subdivide, how do you subdivide the linked info? By area? By half? Keep the same? I think you need to hire a consultant and develop a robust geospatial database solution.

Comment: Okay good to know. Thank you so much for your advice!